# Using Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO

Tags: ada

I'm trying to write the following program:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   type T is range 0 .. 18;
   package IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (T);

begin

   IO.Put (1);

end Main;
```

But when I try compiling, I get the following error messages:

> ```
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:51
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Get" requires completion)
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:56
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Get" requires completion)
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:60
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Put" requires completion)
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:66
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Put" requires completion)
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:71
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Get" requires completion)
> main.adb:6:04: info: in instantiation at a-tiinio.ads:76
> main.adb:6:04: info: "IO" requires body ("Put" requires completion)
> a-tiinio.adb:59:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> a-tiinio.adb:79:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> a-tiinio.adb:100:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> a-tiinio.adb:121:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> a-tiinio.adb:134:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> a-tiinio.adb:147:07: (style) maximum nesting level exceeded
> ```

As far as I understand from section [A.10.8](https://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/aarm/AA-A-10-8.html) of the manual, `Integer_IO` is a generic package that needs to be instantiated with a signed integer. I also tried with `subtype T is Integer` or `Positive`, but I get the same errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your program compiles and runs correctly; as your system appears to be compiling `Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO`, you may have an installation problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you set inappropriate maximum nested level in style checks which provided by compiler switch "-gnatyL" and then set up the compiler to treat all warnings and style checks as errors by "-gnatwe" switch.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a problem in your compiler installation. I can build your code with `gnatmake main.adb`without problems. Are you using gnatmake in your command line or any IDE?

Anyways, i would recommend you the following...

You can use the package "Ada.Integer_Text_IO", e.g.:

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
```

Now you can call: `put(1);`

This is probably the most comfortable way to put integers!